# Where do I put my couchDB views in my installable app?

Tags: web-applications, view, couchdb

so, I'm considering using couchDB as a database for my next project. I want to build an installable webapp: Install it, configure it, run it -- it works. I don't want to build a couchapp, I intend to do this with `Python/Ruby/Node.js`.

Now, with a MySQL database at hand, I'd put my queries right into the code. But I just don't know where I should put my couchDB views. Should I put them on a public couchDB and replicate from that on install, or should I set up some code that inserts the necessary views on first run, or wut?

Answer (score 0):

I'd keep a JSON file in my installation folder, and I'd just insert it into couchdb, little bit like node.js `connect-couchdb` module does: https://github.com/tdebarochez/connect-couchdb/tree/master/lib